# Scaling animation for entire text view android

Tags: android, animation

I have a text view with background color. I want to enlarge/project the whole view using animation. I tried with scale animation only text gets enlarged.I want the whole view to get enlarged. Which animation should I use to attain this? Provide suggestions.

Comment: May be the parent view of text view is the same size like text view. Then your text view is clipped in parent view, and you don't see enlarging.

Answer (score 2):

Add your textview to a relative layout.And apply animation to that layout.

xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:id="@+id/mylayout"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="218dp"
    android:background="#000" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Java:

```
ScaleAnimation animation = new ScaleAnimation(fromXscale, toXscale, fromYscale, toYscale, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float)0.5, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float)0.5);

RelativeLayout rl=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mylayout);

rl.startAnimation(animation);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the textView in relative layout, set the id of relative Layout and do the scale animation to the relative Layout....